# Augment all objects with another class properties/methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Imagine I have two classes

```
class Point {
}

class EditablePoint extends Point {
  // list of additional properties and methods
}

function edit(editablePoint) {
  //
}

let point = new Point();
edit(point);
```

**How can I augment all objects with another class methods/properties?**

Any `prototype` hacks don't work for me. It seems I can't get around this instead of recreating the objects or assigning manually additional properties of the class or using a loop. I would like some one line clean solution.

***Disclaimer***: this looks like an antipattern with which I agree however I have huge arrays of `Point`s and only in super rare occassions I need to edit them and I want to do so in-place without introducing any copying as arrays are HUGE.

Why I don't like having all points have editable properties and want to have them on the prototype:

- each object instance becomes larger and that's the least I want
- it doesnt communicate well to the code reader

Comment: Kind of looks to me like you're trying to ride two horses with one saddle. So, you'd like all `Point` instances to have the methods of `EditablePoint` *but* you don't want to alter the prototype of `Point` *or* assign the methods to the `Point` instances?

Comment: Problem statement is unclear, and the code doesn't explain what you're trying to do. What are 'other objects'? *I have two classes* - and which of them is the one you mentioned as 'another class'? *Any prototype hacks don't work for me.* - what exactly did you try and what wasn't working?

Comment: @MátéSafranka I didn't specify I don't want to alter prototype. I WANT. I just don't know how to do so after objects are already created

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood. Answer coming up.

Comment: @estus the problem is clearly stated isn't it? "How can I augment all objects with another class methods/properties?"

Comment: Don't call them prototype hacks, they're not supposed to be hacks - we're just thinking of them as hacks because of all the syntactic sugar we have now :)

Comment: How are you assigning methods to your classes? Good old function, or arrow function? Just so we know if your object methods go into the prototype, or are just function instances assigned to a property. If you're using arrow functions, calling `Object.assign(objToExtend,  objUsedToExtend)` should be enough.

Comment: @lukas.pukenis It possibly makes sense for you but not everyone is proficient in mind-reading. What are *all objects*? Just every existing object?

Comment: "*Any prototype hacks don't work for me*" - unlikely. Which "prototype hack" do you refer to specifically?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is *technically feasible*:

```
let pointProto = Point.prototype;
let editProto = EditablePoint.prototype;

for (let memberName in editProto) {
    if (typeof editProto[memberName] === 'function'
        && !(memberName in pointProto)) {
        pointProto[memberName] = editProto[memberName];
    }
}
```

This will achieve what you're describing: all instances of the `Point` class will now have the same methods as `EditablePoint` instances do (the `!(memberName in pointProto)` clause ensures we don't overwrite methods that were already defined).

However, as you yourself have said, this is a *massive* antipattern, since at this point you're blurring the line between the two classes to a point where it's unclear why they even exist as separate classes; seeing an array of `Point`s being used as if they were `EditablePoint`s is a 100% sure way to confuse anyone who's reading your code. If you think you need something like this, it's probably better to rethink your model structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.assign` to add properties and `setPrototypeOf` to add methods by setting prototype of `EditablePoint` to prototype of `Point`, but since `EditablePoint` inherits from `Point` you will still have `Point` methods.

```js
class Point {
  constructor() {
    this.point = true;
  }
  foo() {
    console.log('foo')
  }
}

class EditablePoint extends Point {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.editable = true;
  }
  bar() {
    console.log('bar')
  }
}

function edit(editablePoint) {
  Object.assign(editablePoint, new EditablePoint);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(editablePoint, EditablePoint.prototype)
}

let point = new Point();
edit(point);

console.log(point)
point.foo();
point.bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just should not make an `EditablePoint` class that inherits from `Point` and has all the methods necessary for editing. Instead, use composition over inheritance, and make a class

```
class PointEditor {
    constructor(point) {
        this.point = point;
        …
    }
    …
}
```

with all the methods necessary for editing the point associated to the editor. This way, you can instantiate as few / as many `PointEditor`s for the points in your array that you want to edit, without changing anything about how the points in the array are created.